# How to disable acces to subdirectories and files

Tags: directory

I have a situation where I would give a path and the file dialog box opens with the path given, but the user should not have access to change to any other paths from the file dialog box and as well as he should not have access to  subdirectories of the directories displayed in the file dialog box, this is the issue am facing now.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain the context please. This does not sound like a command line related question. Nor related to Nautilus. Is this a coding question? If so ... the language you are using is key information.

Comment: Not only the language, all the toolset could be important, at least the graphic library is.

Comment: Where you want to give the path? Who will be the user? Please make your question more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command in Terminal to lock all the directories under "MyFolder" directory:

> sudo chmod 000 /home/$USER/MyFolder/*

Execute this command to unlock the sub directories:

> sudo chmod 755 /home/$USER/MyFolder/*

**Note:** You must only use this method to lock/unlock folders within your home directory. Do not apply this to operating system folders.